# java: unable to cast an Integer object to String

Tags: java, object, types, casting, type-conversion

I'm trying to concatenate multiple objects inside a String variable called 'update' from a 'data' array within the method 'addClient' below:

```
public int addClient(Object[] data) {

    try {

            if (((String)data[0]).trim().isEmpty() || ((String)data[1]).trim().isEmpty() || ((int)data[2] < 0) || ((int)data[3] <= 0)) {
                return StatusBar.ERR_INVALID_INPUT_CODE;
            }

            // the line below is causing the exception
            String update = "INSERT INTO Client VALUES(" + ((String)data[0]).trim() + "," + ((String)data[1]).trim() + "," + ((Integer)data[3]).intValue() + "," + ((Integer)data[4]).intValue() + "," + ((Boolean)data[2]).booleanValue() + "," + ((String)data[5]).trim() + ")";

            if (statement.executeUpdate(update) != 1) {
                return StatusBar.ERR_INTERNAL_CODE;
            }
     }

     catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return StatusBar.ERR_INTERNAL_CODE;
     }

     return StatusBar.ERR_SUCCESS_CODE;
}
```

However when the code above executes; an exception gets raised showing the following message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>           at Model.addClient(Model.java:43)

The 'data' object array is obtained through the call of the following method:

```
public Object[] getFields() {
                return new Object[]{jTextFieldName.getText(), jTextFieldAddress.getText(),
                                    jComboBoxType.getSelectedIndex(),
                                    jSpinnerPhone.getValue(), jSpinnerFax.getValue(),
                                    jTextFieldWebsite.getText()};
        }
```

I did many searches and tried many methods including `String.valueOf` and `Integer.toString`, but without any success ..

Why I'm getting such behavior? How can it be solved?

Comment: You get such a behavior because, at line 43, you're trying to cast an Integer to a String. Since an Integer is not a String, it fails. I'd radically change the design and stop passing arrays of objects around. Instead, pass instances of a well-defined class, with named and typed properties. Putting one instruction per line, and using a debugger, would help finding the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Even `System.out.println(data[4].toString());` results in the same exception .. I updated the question to explain how the data array was constructed.

Comment: Before you do the casting and get an exception it would be better to check if your Object is actually a String. You can do so with `instanceof` operator

Comment: No, it doesn't. There's no way calling toString() on an object causes a ClassCastException like the one you have. Again, stop using Object[] to store your information. Create a class with properties named name, address, number, phone, fax and website. Pass an instance of this class instead of an Object[].

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the suggestion, now things have became much simpler by using an instance of a defined class instead. But I noted that the openjdk javac compiler doesn't recompile the classes unless I `rm *.class` .. so I think that the type casting problem was in fact caused by the inability of the compiler to detect the code updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of your `data` array can be of any reference type. Therefore you can't cast them to `String` without checking their type first.

Luckily, you can simply call their `toString` method instead.

Change

```
((String)data[0])
```

to

```
data[0].toString()
```

Comment: `System.out.println(data[4].toString());` results in the same exception

Comment: @Kais I find that hard to believe (unless `data[4]` is an instance of a class whose `toString` implementation attempts to cast some `Integer` to `String`).

Comment: I updated the question in order to explain how the data array is constructed .. What do you think?

Comment: @Kais Perhaps you are not running the code you think you are running. Make sure your code passes compilation after your latest changes.

Comment: I noted that the openjdk javac compiler doesn't recompile the classes unless I `rm *.class` .. so I think that the type casting problem was in fact caused by the inability of the compiler to detect the code updates.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options casting to String. 
You chose the "simple" option that will work only if the object is really a String, and you just need to down-cast it (from Object) to String.

Try using one of the following options:

- new String (your-Integer-here);
- (your-Integer-here).toString();
- (your-Integer-here) + "";

Let me know if it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting to String, you can call `.toString()` method on object, if that is your intention.

You are casting your object

i.e

`if (((String)data[0]).trim().isEmpty() || ((String)data[1]).trim().isEmpty() || ((int)data[2] < 0) || ((int)data[3] <= 0))` to

`if (data[0].toString().trim().isEmpty() || (data[1].toString().trim().isEmpty() || ((int)data[2] < 0) || ((int)data[3] <= 0))`

Assuming `data[3]` and `data[2]` are of type Integers.

*<sub>PS:You can also log the values, to make sure what the values are.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below and let me know how it goes.

```
private static void concater(){
    String[] data={"abc","def","23","45","true","xyz"};

    String update = "INSERT INTO Client VALUES(" + ((String)data[0]).trim() + "," + ((String)data[1]).trim() + "," + Integer.parseInt(data[2]) + "," +
    Integer.parseInt(data[3]) + "," + Boolean.parseBoolean(data[4]) + "," + ((String)data[5]).trim() + ")";

    System.out.println(update);  //INSERT INTO Client VALUES(abc,def,23,45,true,xyz)


}
```